# Codeigniter Mail does send but can't receive it

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, config

After reading alot, i can't manage to receive a mail with the code i have. It sends perfectly but i never receive an email. Is there maybe a config problem? provider = one.com

```
function sendmail(){

    $message = "Aanvraag van: ".$this->input->post('inputName')."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "Vraag: ".$this->input->post('inputVraag')."\r\n";
    $message .= "Telefoon nr: ".$this->input->post('inputTel')."\r\n";
    $message .= "Email: ".$this->input->post('inputEmail')."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "Bericht: ".$this->input->post('inputBericht')."\r\n\r\n";

        $config = array();
   $config['smtp_host'] = "send.one.com";
   $config['smtp_port'] = "25";
   $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
   $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';

        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->from($this->input->post('inputEmail'),$this->input->post('inputName'));
        $this->email->to('anemailaddress@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('Aanvraag website');
        $this->email->message($message);

        if($this->email->send()){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Danku voor uw email');
            redirect('welcome','refresh');  
        }

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();

    }
```

Comment: Where do you define `$config`?

Answer (score 0):

Show your $config.

Are you sure that mail server is properly configured ?

just try to send mail with this simple script:

```
    <?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

@edit
New soultuion:
try port 25 and host mailout.one.com

Comment: Edited; probably my config is the problem but don't really know how to configer it

Comment: @edit
i found new solution, try port 25 and host mailout.one.com

Comment: Ok Now i received a email. But it contains alot of stuff likeThis is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_5315f69b11646
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Comment: Check $config['crlf'] = "\r\n"; or $config['crlf'] = "\n";

Comment: Unable to send email using PHP mail()Your server might not be configured to send email using this method. With port 25 and mailout.one.com

Comment: Can you post here detail of correct and incorrect mail?

Comment: Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Wed, 5 Mar 2014 08:21:05 +0000
From: "efef" <kristof@bearcom.com>
Return-Path: <kristof@bearcom.com>
Reply-To: "kristof@bearcom.com" <kristof@bearcom.com>
X-Sender: kristof@bearcom.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5316de715393f@bearcom.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5316de7153980"


=?iso-8859-1?Q?Aanvraag_website?=

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your `$config`, something like:

```
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['mailtype'] = 'text';
$this->email->initialize($config);
```